# Links not working in JavaScript drop down menu

Tags: javascript, css

I am a beginner to JavaScript and can't figure out how to get links working within this dd menu. I'm assuming it has something to do with the javascript function closing the dropdown menu wherever you click overriding the links.

#### HTML

```
<div id="right_box">
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="dropdown" class="ddmenu"> User Settings 
            <ul> 
                <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </div> 
    </div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $("#dropdown").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
            $(this).removeClass("open");
            $(this).children("ul").slideUp("fast");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("open");
            $(this).children("ul").slideDown("fast");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Conor Add it to the question.  It's of little use in a comment.

Comment: @RicardoLohmann It is there in the top buddy!

Comment: @PraveenKumar When I asked it wasn't.

Comment: @Conor It is working perfectly. What is the issue? See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hVthb/

Comment: Should I show the CSS, could that be the problem? When I click on it links in the drop down it just closes.

Answer (score 3):

It happens because you're using `e.preventDefault()`, remove it.
When you use it you stop the default `a` action.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PtYtf/11/)